# Read a NUL terminated string in a byte stream

Tags: rust

I have a packet of bytes that I have read from a TCP connection:

```
let x = [82, 0, 0, 0, 10, 53, 46, 53, 46, 53, 48, 45, 77, 97, 114,
         105, 97, 68, 66, 0, 235, 16, 194, 9, 65, 41, 73, 112,
         122, 53, 53, 76, 0, 255, 247, 8, 2, 0, 15, 160, 21, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 92, 108, 41, 37, 124, 99, 93, 42,
         84, 75, 92, 108, 0, 109, 121, 115, 113, 108, 95, 110, 97,
         116, 105, 118, 101, 95, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114,
         100, 0];
```

In there is a NUL-terminated C string:

```
77, 97, 114, 105, 97, 68, 66, 0
```

How can I read that NUL terminated into a standard Rust `&str` or `String`.

At the moment I am trying something like

```
let cstr = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(&x[12 ..]);
assert!(cstr.is_ok());
println!("username {:?}", cstr);
```

But the assert is failing. I'm sure I am missing something simple.

Comment: The docs for CStr::from_bytes_with_nul say "This function will cast the provided bytes to a CStr wrapper after ensuring that it is null terminated and does not contain any interior nul bytes."

Comment: The accepted solution there is scanning the array for a null byte which doesn't seem optimised. It also uses unsafe which I would like to avoid. I would like to know why from_bytes_with null asserts in this case.
Also how to pass in a slice instead of an array.
Thanks

Comment: I thought the function may stop after encountering the first null. As I am passing in a slice at position twelve (77) I though it may just read up to the following NULL but obviously I must be wrong.

Comment: @GlennPierce if you disagree with or just plain dislike the answers on a duplicate question, it is recommended that you place a bounty on that question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Also, you don't **need** `unsafe`; that's only due to the fact that OP "knows" it to be UTF-8. Substitute the safe variant instead.